# expect usage after ssh connection

Tags: expect

I am able to use expect to connect automatically with SSH. However, I have a lot of shell commands and shell conditions to be executed or tested after the connection. I am wondering how I can deal with this situation. It looks like putting the shell commands in the expect script and use `send` is not a good option. Are there any other options?

Comment: Do not use expect but some of the Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. modules for SSH available.

Comment: Are the shell commands to be run on the remote system you make the ssh connection to?  Why do you think using send in the Expect script is not a good option?

Comment: @salva: can perl module do this? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Colin: because sometimes, I may need to write some conditional expressions, some shell subroutines, etc. Also what if I need to use `expect` again in the script?

Comment: `expect` is fine for this job. Try using [`autoexpect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/autoexpect.1.html) to record a sample session -- that will give you a template script that can be edited to use for other servers.

Comment: @Quiang: Expect incorporates all the facilites of the Tcl language, including conditions, branching, loops, subroutines and a lot more, just in a slightly different style from shell scripts.  And of course you can have many `expect` statements within one script.  More background info is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: @Colin: can you please give me an example of using `expect` inside `expect`? For example, after ssh to a machine, do a scp.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can use [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH2), [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) or even the old [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl)

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('host.example.com', user => 'jsmith', password => 'jsmith2011');
$ssh->error and die "Unable to connect to remote host: " . $ssh->error;

$ssh->system("ls /etc");
my $output = $ssh->capture("rgrep hello /usr/share/doc");
$ssh->scp_get("/var/log/messages", "/tmp/remote_log");
# ...
```

Comment: @salva, I tried this, but I got an error `Unable to connect to remote host: unable to establish master SSH connection: control command failed: child exited with code 1` Do you know what happens here? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you are not using OpenSSH client or have some file permissions issue. Follow the trouble-shooting guide included on the module documentation!

Comment: @salva: what did you mean by "I am using OpenSSH"? Surely I am, since I did use `use Net::OpenSSH;`. I have used `strict_mode => 0` too.

Comment: It refers to OpenSSH ssh client. If you are on Linux or in any *BSD your are already using it. If you are running Solaris or AIX you probably don't.

Comment: @salva: how to tell whether the OpenSSH client is running or not? I am running the perl script on a Linux machine.

Comment: @salva: the output is `OpenSSH_3.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7a Feb 19 2003`. So I am running ssh client, but I still got that error.

Comment: 3.9 is too old, at least 4.1 is required